# Fixed cell size table with Java-FX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I've been fighting with this for some time, and finally figured I needed some help.

I am trying to create a table where each cell displays a particular color. This is dynamically created based on a user selected image.

I got it to work with a TilePane, but because of the size of the table, it was running extremely slow.

Currently, I am trying to make it work using a TableView. The TableView is being created, but not populated. My code to create the TableView, and my custom TableCell class, is below.

My main question is this: Is this the best way to go about this? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for the awesome assistance I always see here.

Code to create TableView:

```
private ObservableList<ObservableList<Stitch>> stitchList;
private TableView<Stitch> pattern;

@Override
protected TableView<Stitch> call() throws Exception {
    for (int i=0; i< stitchList.size(); i++) {
        TableColumn<Stitch, Color> column = new TableColumn<>();
        column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Stitch, Color>, ObservableValue<Color>>() {

             public ObservableValue<Color> call(CellDataFeatures<Stitch, Color> stitch) {
                 return stitch.getValue().getDisplayColorProperty();
             }
             });

        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Stitch, Color>, TableCell<Stitch, Color>>() {
             @Override public TableCell<Stitch, Color> call(TableColumn<Stitch, Color> list) {
                 return new StitchCell();
             }
         });

        //Set column sizes
        column.setMinWidth(10);
        column.setMaxWidth(10);
        pattern.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    return pattern;
} // End Call
```

Code for custom cell class

```
public class StitchCell extends TableCell<Stitch, Color> {

@Override 
protected void updateItem(Color color, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(color, empty);

    if (empty || color == null) {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
    } else {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + Integer.toHexString(color.hashCode()));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you adding any items to the table anywhere? You show code to add the columns, but no code to actually add items.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I have a 2D array of nested observable lists, but I'm not sure how to add the data to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `TableView<S>`, `S` is the type of the object displayed in each row of the table. The `items` property of the table, which is an `ObservableList<S>` contains the collection of items, each one of which is displayed in a table row.

If your data is in the form `ObservableList<ObservableList<Stitch>> stitchList`, then you need a `TableView<ObservableList<Stitch>>`. (In other words, `S` is `ObservableList<Stitch>`.) Each element of `stitchList`, which is an `ObservableList<Stitch>` represents a row in the table.

`TableView` is not designed with `ObservableList<ObservableList>` as the primary use case for representing data, so you need to do a little bit of work to get the `cellValueFactory` to work right. If you are certain that every row has the same number of items, you can perhaps minimize this a bit, but you need something like the following:

```
TableView<ObservableList<Stitch>> pattern = new TableView<>();
ObservableList<ObservableList<Stitch>> stitchList = ... ;

// Set items (i.e. rows) in table:
pattern.setItems(stitchList);

// iterate through all rows:

for (ObservableList<Stitch> row : pattern) {
    // if this row contains more elements than columns we have already created,
    // (must be true on first row, may be true on subsequent rows if data not rectangular)
    // create a new column for each additional element
    for (int i = pattern.getColumns().size(); i < row.size() ; i++) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color> column = new TableColumn<>();
        final int columnIndex = i ;
        column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color>, ObservableValue<Color>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Stitch> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<Stitch>, Stitch>> stitch) {
                return  stitch.getValue() // the row value, i.e. an ObservableList<Stitch>
                            .get(columnIndex) // the Stitch for this cell
                            .getDisplayColorProperty();
            }
        });

        column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color>, TableCell<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color> call(TableColumn<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color> col) {
                return new StitchCell();
            }
        });

        column.setMinWidth(10);
        column.setMaxWidth(10);
        pattern.getColumns().add(column);
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 8, you can replace the `Callback`s with lambda expressions, and get rid of the ugliest parts of the code:

```
for (ObservableList<Stitch> row : pattern) {
    // if this row contains more elements than columns we have already created,
    // (must be true on first row, may be true on subsequent rows if data not rectangular)
    // create a new column for each additional element
    for (int i = pattern.getColumns().size(); i < row.size() ; i++) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<Stitch>, Color> column = new TableColumn<>();
        final int columnIndex = i ;
        column.setCellValueFactory( rowData -> 
            rowData.getValue() // the row value, i.e. an ObservableList<Stitch>
                .get(columnIndex) // the Stitch for this cell
                .getDisplayColorProperty() );

        column.setCellValueFactory(col -> new StitchCell());

        column.setMinWidth(10);
        column.setMaxWidth(10);
        pattern.getColumns().add(column);
    }
}
```